# How to install Cassandra in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, minikube

I was wondering if there is a way to install a cassandra cluster locally in minikube. I found some solutions just to install it in cloud provisioners like GCP but I need to install in my dev environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to install cassandra using [helm charts](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/cassandra) in minikube `v1.9.2` running k8s `v1.17.4` on Ubuntu `16.04 Xenial` like this:

```
git clone git@github.com:helm/charts.git
cd charts
kubectl create ns cassandra
helm install cassandra --namespace "cassandra" incubator/cassandra

$ kubectl get pods,svc -n=cassandra
NAME              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/cassandra-0   1/1     Running   0          3m52s
pod/cassandra-1   0/1     Running   0          104s
NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                        AGE
service/cassandra   ClusterIP   None         <none>        7000/TCP,7001/TCP,7199/TCP,9042/TCP,9160/TCP   3m52s

## see status of cassandra cluster
$ kubectl exec -it --namespace cassandra cassandra-0 nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.18.0.6  89.13 KiB  256          65.4%             09486d44-43d6-47eb-b455-8856d566ac0a  rack1
UN  172.18.0.4  74.93 KiB  256          67.5%             d7c24d6a-0ba5-498f-a65c-4a858cba282e  rack1
UN  172.18.0.5  74.92 KiB  256          67.1%             14c2eea0-efdf-444e-9e97-936d9710c2eb  rack1

## my helm, minikube and k8s versions
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.2", GitCommit:"19e47ee3283ae98139d98460de796c1be1e3975f", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.5"}

$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.9.2
commit: 93af9c1e43cab9618e301bc9fa720c63d5efa393

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.4", GitCommit:"8d8aa39598534325ad77120c120a22b3a990b5ea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-12T21:03:42Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.4", GitCommit:"8d8aa39598534325ad77120c120a22b3a990b5ea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-12T20:55:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

[This link](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/cassandra#persist-data) has steps to create a `StorageClass` to persist data in cassandra.

[This link](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/cassandra) has more information about cassandra helm charts and its configurations.

Comment: I was able to install cassandra but there is a problem with the pod, it says: `running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "cassandra-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims` In my values.yaml I enabled the persistance and `storageClass: "-"` but it does not work. PD. I'm using a Mac. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try local storage class in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local, https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local.

Comment: @BraulioDavid is `storage-provisioner` enabled in your minikube? run `minikube addons list` to check it!

Comment: @willrof yes, it is enabled. I finally got installed it using this helm chart https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/cassandra